# Django OperationalError 2019 Can't initialize character set utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, django, heroku, django-celery, amazon-rds

I have struggled with this all day and have not been able to find a solution or even the root cause of the error.  When I run my app locally it works fine.  My production instance is using Heroku cedar stack and Amazon RDS MySQL databases.

In my settings file I have:  `'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}`

When I push to Heroku it crashes with the error: `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2019, "Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)")`

The exception location: `/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in set_character_set, line 298`

I have created the appropriate Data Base parameters with Amazon RDS MySQL and are currently set as follows:

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                     |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.13.R1/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I am running:

```
MySQL 5.6.13
MySQL-python==1.2.4
```

Thanks in advance for your help.  Let me know if there are more details that I am missing.

Comment: UPDATE: If I run a 

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%character%';

It is showing all the correct utf8mb4 values, but these variables are not being applied to the actual database instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the issue falls on Heroku and their lack of support for the needed library:

Here is what the support folks at Heroku told me:

> This encoding requires an up-to-date version of MySQL's libmysqlclient
>   C shared library. Sorry but we don't currently have plans to upgrade
>   this library in the immediate future. You can build your own versions
>   of binary dependencies by following the instructions at
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries

Comment: did you end up solving this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

For future readers: the solution to this specific issue as of late 2014 is to use the cedar-14 stack, which includes up to date mysql binaries (tested by me).
A general solution would be to compile your own binaries and create a custom buildpack, as [advised by the heroku people](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/mysqlclient-with-utf8mb4-support-in-ruby-buildpack/890/2).

Answer (score -3):

is utf8mb4 for example. Many of those weird picture like characters are.